# How to delegate work and still keep relationships with colleagues

Tags: conflict-resolution

I had recently started a job, some time back.

At first, I took on everything that was given to me, in terms of workload.   I took on other people’s work, as I was afraid of getting fired, or, not making probation.

I made probation and then senior management realised that I was doing work which was the responsibility of other staff,..., and at the end of the month,..., which was an extremely busy period,..., with extreme deadlines,... it was way too much for me to do.

It was decided that data be entered into a CRM, by the Sales Team, and that I would be responsible for double checking the data and making amendments,..., and other tasks.

At first, this was very difficult to enforce.

Teams were up in arms,..., regarding the newly delegated tasks, complaining constantly to management and even taking personal shots at my personal life,..., as they did not want to do this.

Management kept enforcing that they needed to do it,..., but with great resistance and anger from teams.

When the team member would leave the entire worksheet of the CRM blank,..., I would screenshot the blank sections and kindly remind them in an email, cc’ing their manager that these were the fields that they would needed to complete.

They would call their manager, angrily,..., saying that they were way too busy,..., (which was clearly a lie),..., and the decision would be enforced by their manager,..., but with great difficulty.

The teams then made comments at lunchtime to each other which were personal negative comments regarding my personal life,..., and would rather than see this as a decision that was now being enforced by management,..., they would view this as a playground school fight,..., where they would now need to bully.

Trying to now build a relationship with the team which I was to support was very difficult.

My question is,...;

Anytime that a decision is made to delegate work to another team member,..., there is always resistance.  People always don’t understand the logical reasons behind it.   There will always be those who will resist it,..., and it will now need to be enforced.

How do I go abouts ensuring that a decision made for a logical reason by management is enforced,..., and still keep relationships with the team?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, you don't have a relationship with the team. They argue with you consistently and say disparaging things behind your back (and to your face too?) This may be petty and unprofessional but it does mean that your relationship is not going well. And don't think that it was going well before. When everyone was dumping their work on you, your relationship wasn't a good one then either. I can't tell you if you can repair relations with these people, but if you really want to try then maybe. I also can't tell you if you should, only you can decide, but this is a rather toxic position to be in.

> How do I go abouts ensuring that a decision made for a logical reason by management is enforced

**You Don't**

This is part of your problem. You have been playing the hall monitor who makes sure everyone is following the rules. People don't like the hall monitor. You may have felt compelled to play that role because people were dumping their workload on you. You will need to start learning how to resist doing people's work without resorting to CCing their manager unless it's absolutely necessary.

- Show up.
- Do your work.
- Let others shirk their work. But don't do it for them.
- If you are blocked inform your manager you are blocked.
- Let managers do the enforcing.

As you build a relationship with people, which may be rather slow going now, you can start going to them directly and gently requesting they accomplish what they need. "I can't do X until you finish Y. Will you please let me know when it is ready?" Politeness goes a long way here.

Good luck. It sounds like a difficult environment to be in, but you may be able to improve it slowly.

Answer (score -3):

After reading the full post I can't find a link with the title: you are not a manager so you should not be delegating...

> How do I go abouts ensuring that a decision made for a logical reason by management is enforced,..., and still keep relationships with the team?

You write to *your* manager about *your* situation and what is blocking *you*, better if without naming names (when possible).

It looks like you are not a manager so it is not your duty to deal with what your colleagues (don't) do: that's their manager's job.

In my opinion you greatly overstepped the boundaries of your role writing directly to a colleague that is not your subordinate cc'ing a boss and this may be one of the reason behind your colleagues unfriendliness.

A direct message like 'could you please check x y z' could have been appropriate (even if you both know that the colleague is behind schedule or plain lazy), but now you should step back and do your job, stop patrolling.

Let the dust set and maybe in the next months something could slowly begin to change.